# SQL query for determining presence in table

Tags: sql, database

I have a student id and multiple tables in my database all for info of students such that given any id, it is present only in one table. Each table has attribute Student id.

Given a student id, how to use SQL query to determine table has the info of student with that student id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM table WHERE studentID = @input)
   BEGIN
      -- do stuff
   END
```

or slightly less fancy

```
   IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 studentID FROM table WHERE studentID = @input)
   BEGIN
      -- do stuff
   END
```

you could also make a lookup view / query.  something like this:

```
   SELECT sudentID, 'Table1' as Location
   FROM 'Table1'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT sudentID, 'Table2' as Location
   FROM 'Table2'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT sudentID, 'Table3' as Location
   FROM 'Table3'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT sudentID, 'Table4' as Location
   FROM 'Table4'
```

Then query this view for location.  This can be useful if you need to joins

Answer (score 0):

I'm only a MySQL beginner, but I would approach the problem by selecting * from each table in turn:

select * from `table` order by `student_id`;

And then, for every student_id, see if some row returned from that select has that student_id.

Yes, this is totally brute force, and there are no doubt many more sophisticated, faster solutions. But that's how I would do it at this point in my MySQL journey.

HTH. Better solutions are solicited and very welcome.